# How to add each vector element to each list element in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

Reproducible example:

```
A <- list(1,2,3)
B <- c(10,20,30)
```

I want to add each vector element of B to each list element with the same index. The expected result is:

```
> AB
[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 22

[[3]]
[1] 33
```

How to do this without using a loop?

Comment: how did you get 11 21 and 30?

Comment: Shouldn't the output rather be as in my answer below?

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map`.

```
Map(`+`, A, B)
# [[1]]
# [1] 11
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 22
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 33
```

Answer (score 1):

```
purrr::map2(A, B, sum)

[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 22

[[3]]
[1] 33
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out following way:

```
AB <- lapply(A, function(x) A[[x]] + B[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of each element in the `list` is 1, it may be more efficient to `unlist` and do this once and `relist` back

```
relist(unlist(A) + B, A)
[[1]]
[1] 11

[[2]]
[1] 22

[[3]]
[1] 33
```